# Как правильно оптимизировать сео страницу (см. описание)?

Tags: seo, поисковая-оптимизация

Помогите пожалуйста, с вопросом оптимизации страницы. Суть ее в следующем: это страница посвящена продаже задания , например: задание по математике с фотографиями условия и самим условием (текстом) , так же думаю название задания, чтобы там были слова из условия. Ещё в условии будет город , вуз, предмет,
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

(кароче на картинке все области динамические, а красным зарисованы статические. Также есть ещё снизу несколько статически блоков - инфа о сайте, ответы на вопросы и ТД. 
Помогите пожалуйста, что здесь нужно добавлять в тег head , какие теги и данные в этих тегах стоит размещать (хотелось бы услышать что-то типа инструкции: 
1) добавить в title N слов из такой то секции, 2) добавить ... И тд)
Также хочется услышать, возможно стоит что-то поменять в выводе данных на самой странице ( типа убрать вывод города или добавить что-то ) 
Задача по условию, возможно вузу находилась страница.
Буду крайне благодарен за развернутый ответ!
P.S. на картинке тестовая версия страницы, так что данные тоже рандомные. Конечно же МГУ не в Харькове))

Answer (score 1):

Вы слишком многого хотите. Гуглите в сторону низкочастотных запросов. Оптимизируя вашу конкретную страницу под конкретный НЧ (низкочастотный запрос), вы можете добиться результатов.

Например. "**Груминг-салон**" - это ВЧ (высокочастотный запрос). По нему у вас уйма конкурентов, даже с учетом региональной выдачи поисковиков. А вот "**Груминг-салон в Харькове**" - это уже СЧ (среднечастотный запрос), почти НЧ - по нему в выдаче Гугла по Харькову у вас будет несколько конкурентов. Запрос же вида "**Груминг-салон в Харькове Полтавский Шлях**" (реально существовал такой, несколько месяцев назад переехал) - это чистой воды НЧ и "затачивать" вашу страничку нужно именно под него.

Как оптимизировать под него страницу? Этот запрос должен входить в  мета-теги `title`, `description` и `keywords`, `тег` h1 или `h2` вашей страницы, присутствовать на ней еще несколько раз в явной форме (прямым вхождением) или немного видоизменённым, например так: "Груминг-салон в Харькове на Полтавском Шляхе".

Однако не переусердствуйте - переоптимизация страницы может привести к т.н. "тошноте" - это когда показатели вашей страницы выбиваются из среднестатистических и алгоритмы поисковиков это замечают, после чего налагают санкции.

Как не дойти до "тошноты"? Анализируйте страницы сайтов-конкурентов, которые находятся в ТОП3 выдачи по интересующим вас запросам. Если они с такой оптимизацией оказались в самом верху - значит, она удовлетворяет алгоритмам поисковой системы, не так ли?

Ну и ещё не забывайте про внешние ссылки на страницы вашего сайта, как безанкорные, так и с нужными анкорами, как nofollow-ссылки, так и передающие полный вес. Плюс внутренняя перелинковка на сайте. Эти вещи тоже должны быть сделаны как у лидеров выдачи по нужным вам запросам.

А вообще по SEO надо спрашивать на других ресурсах, здесь сеошников не так много.

Comment: +1 За "Полтавский Шлях"! Классное название! :-D